# How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception?

Tags: android, firebase

I tried all the solutions which are available at internet, but cant fix this problem. Please help me how to fix this exception. It cannot allow me to add any Java class in my project.

**build.gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.firza.map"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
  }


   dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
 }
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
  public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,View.OnClickListener {
private GoogleMap mMap;
MapView mapView;
Button btn_rest;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.activity_maps,null);
    mapView=(MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    btn_rest=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_rest);
    btn_rest.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.i("okkkk","ojooooooo ");
}
}
```

**Exception**

```
 02-12 19:04:56.737 23160-23160/com.example.firza.map E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.firza.map, PID: 23160
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)
   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)
   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5020)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4594)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4534)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5304)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: That's because you didn't override `attachBaseContext` in your Application subclass in order to install multidex

Comment: @EpicPandaForceplesae tell me how and where to override attachBaseContext ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **[GoogleMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/)** then it will be better call **play-services-maps** instead of **play-services** .

**Don't**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

**Do**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1' // or 9.8.0
```

Comment: Thanks Now I understand it is a good practice to compile only related dependencies of google not all

Comment: @android yes .Move ahead .

Answer (score 2):

Don't import the whole google play services library, only import the dependencies you need.
Go over this list, and figure out what you need exactly.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project
You'll need to add the firebase dependency where FirebaseOptions class is in.

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1"
```

Its not a good practice to import the full dependency since you might reach the max method count (dex count).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing firebase dependencies in your `build.gradle`.  For example

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the firebase docs at this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup,
you have to add *Firebase SDK* dependency and the apply *plugin line* in your module Gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```